# Debian 8 iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode missing

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian

I met an issue while I was installing the Debian 8. 
It pops up that `The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode`.
I've searched Google and it stated that it is due to the driver being a "non-free" driver for Intel Wireless AC 8260.

I've also notice that I can get the latest driver build at the link below. http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

But I can not find the exact same `.ucode`. Is this something I can build from source or any other hint for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is a bit of a puzzle. First, the reference you give is totally irrelevant, it concerns *Broadcom*'s cards, not Intel's.

With that out of the way, I am puzzled that you should need version **8** of the microcode: according to [the Linux Kernel Wireless page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi), AC-8260  is available from kernel 4.1 onward, and it requires the microcode versions 13 and on. If you have a kernel 4.1 or later, you are done: download the firmware file from the link above, unwrap it, and place it where needed:

```
  mkdir tmp
  cd tmp
  wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
  gunzip iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz 
  tar xvf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tar 
  cp iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode /lib/firmware
```

If you have an older kernel, you should definitely update it, there is no good reason for keeping one so outdated. If you cannot do that, you will have to install `iwlwifi` from the kernel backports. But we'll cross that bridge when we get there.

Comment: yes. I am going to update the kernel to 4.4 that I think it is the easy way.