# Where to find iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode

Tags: linux, drivers, debian

I've got the latest Debian version, 8.6 from the official website and when I'm installing it I get an error saying `iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode` is missing.

After reading [Debian 8 iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1125770/debian-8-iwlwifi-8000-8-ucode-missing) I went to the suggested website and I've got the driver, but it is `iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode`. In that answer it also says to update the kernel, but I'm assuming I have the latest version.

As the title says - where may I get `iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode`?. Alternatively how may I a newer version of kernel assuming there is a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

From [this Intel's wiki page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#firmware), I gather that your Wi-Fi card has either of these chipsets: Intel® Wireless 8260 or Intel® Wireless 4165, and they appear to be supported since kernel versions 4.1 and 4.3, respectively, while stock Debian 8.6 has kernel 3.16.

The fact the module asks the userspace to load `iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode` is supposedly due to the fact that's what encoded in the `iwlwifi` module:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo iwlwifi | grep 'firmware:.*8000'
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
```

### Solutions

So what you can do about this?

#### Upgrading to Stretch

First, I'd suggest you to just upgrade to Stretch: it has just entered the "soft freeze" stage, with the "full freeze" is due on February, 5.  This means there will be no sweeping changes which make the "testing" Debian's variant to be inconvenient for use by inexperienced users.  Stretch is shipped with kernel 4.8, so your Wi-Fi chipset is supported, and all you will need to do is to enable non-free section of the archive and install the `firmware-iwlwifi` package.

#### Working with backports

Alternatively, you can [enable the `jessie-backports` section of the archive](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports) and install the kernel (4.8 is available) and `firmware-iwlwifi` from there.

Backports are enabled by including something like

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main non-free
```

in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and performing `apt update`.

You will then either directly tell apt the release you need like

```
# apt install linux-image-4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
# apt install -t jessie-backports firmware-iwlwifi
```

or "pinnning" the versions of just these two packages by names as
explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

**Update:** on my Stretch system I have:

```
$ /sbin/modinfo iwlwifi|grep '8000.*ucode'
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C--24.ucode
```

which oddly does not appear to correlate with the firmware [files provided by the `firmware-iwlwifi` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-iwlwifi/filelist) but does appear to be covered by that firmware downloaded from the Intel's site.